# Will formatting my drive TRIM my SSD?

Tags: ext4, ssd, mkfs, trim

Will a standard fresh linux (Ubuntu 11.10 to be exact) install and drive re-format (full) successfully TRIM my SSD, or do I need to do something extra?

I know that ext4 will TRIM blocks on erase when I specify the `discard` option, but I want to start with a completely TRIMmed drive if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TRIM is a command that [needs to be sent for individual blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM#Operation). I have asked the question before ([What is the recommended way to empty a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/42266/6969)) and it is suggested to use [ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/t/a/ATA_Secure_Erase_936d.html), a command that is sent to the device to clear all data.

Answer (score 6):

`mkfs.ext4` has an extra option `-E discard` to send TRIM for appropriate blocks when creating the filesystem.

I can't tell whether the installer uses this option, or whether it is used by `mkfs.ext4` by default, but at least you can explicitly use it when creating the filesystems on your own.

Comment: In `man mkfs.ext4` it says "discard: Attempt  to discard blocks at mkfs time [...]  This is set as default." There is also a nodiscard option.

Answer (score 4):

Quick steps and results (summarised from the [ATA Secure Erase page](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/t/a/ATA_Secure_Erase_936d.html)) follow: If the output is not what is expected, see the full page. Replace `/dev/X` with your device.

1. `hdparm -I /dev/X` should include "not frozen" - if frozen (see notes below on what went wrong for me):

   - Suspend the computer, complete the rest of these steps then power off *(see notes)*
   - or try `printf mem > /sys/power/state` (from the comments; didn't work for me - permission denied)
2. `hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass password /dev/X`
3. `hdparm -I /dev/X` should include "enabled"
4. `hdparm --user-master u --security-erase password /dev/X`
5. `hdparm -I /dev/X` should include "not enabled"

From the page's results, it *seems* that these steps should be able to be done in a couple of minutes on an Intel X25-M 80GB SSD. *Correction: On my Intel X25-M, I was done in just over a minute: step 2 is instant.*

**Notes on unfreezing via suspend**:
Suspending my computer to unfreeze the disk worked for me. I:

1. installed Ubuntu
2. booted it
3. added graphics drivers
4. Rebooted - but it froze on shutdown
5. Reset power, and found an unbootable system.

Re-launching the install showed that there were no partitions on my drive. It seems that bypassing the BIOS security left my partitions in memory of some kind.

Comment: If it's frozen, you may want to try unfreezing it by suspending the system to memory. `printf mem > /sys/power/state` usually does the trick.